# What's the significance of Mṛta Sanjeevani Vidyā, when sages (like Bhṛgu Rishi) can revive dead people just by their tapas itself?

Tags: mantras, rishi, death, life, tapasya

As I ask in [this Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44657/mr%CC%A3ta-sanjeevani-mantra) about some of my doubts in reference to the *Mṛta Sanjeevani Mantra* (मृत संजीवनी मंत्र),
similarly, there have been several instances when sages have been able to revive the "apparently" dead people just via their penance aggregated austerities (*tapas*).

Some examples are:

- [Revival of Kavyamāta by *Bhṛgu Rishi*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-is-the-story-of-vishnu-killing-sage-bhrighus-wife-kavyamata)
- [Revival of *Renukā* (*Parshurām's* mother) by  *Jamadagni*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35357/did-parashurama-perform-any-expiation-for-killing-his-mother)
- [And several other](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/resurrection-stories-in-hindu-scriptures/30009#30009)

So, **my question is**, what's the significance to specifically obtain the *Mṛta Sanjeevani Mantra Vidyā*, when sages are very well in possession of the powers (due to their *tapasyā*) to revive dead people (in some cases, despite getting "beheaded" by *Vishnu* himself or his *aṃśa avatāra*)?

Comment: what is the significance of having a nuclear bomb when you can go around setting fire to each individual house ?